# Delete children and parent with the least amount of SQL queries

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following JPA entities:

```
// Father

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "GODFATHER_ID", nullable = false)
private GodFather godfather;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Child> children;
```

```
// Child
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FATHER_ID")
private Father father;
```

I have one Spring repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Father, UUID> {
    void deleteFathersByGodfatherId(UUID godfatherId);
}
```

When I call `deleteFathersByGodfatherId` from a Service, Hibernates generates *x* + *y* queries where
*x* = number of children
*y* = number of fathers

---

I tried to modify the repository to look like this:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query("""
        DELETE FROM Father f
        WHERE f.godfather.id = :godfatherId
        """)
    void deleteFathersByGodfatherId(UUID godfatherId);

    @Modifying
    @Query("""
        DELETE FROM Child c
            WHERE c.father.id IN : fatherIds
            """)
    void deleteChildrenByFatherIds(List<UUID> fatherIds);
```

And then:

```
deleteChildrenByFatherIds(...);
deleteFathersByGodfatherId(godFather.getId());
```

This fails with an integrity constraint error. These are the queries generated by Hibernate:

```
delete 
    from
        child c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.father_id in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

and

```
 delete 
    from
        father c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.godfather_id=?
```

The second query fails with:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (...) violated - child record found.
```

Oracle is complaining that when deleting the "fathers" the foreign key from father to child is still somehow active, even if the first `DELETE` query should have remove all the "children"

---

So, ultimately, is there a way to remove a father-children hierarchy with 2 DELETE queries?

A notes:

I'm using [Enver](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) to audit my Entities, not sure if this plays a role?

Comment: You are issuing two very different queries - how are you sure that the list children you've cleared is all grand children of the grandfather instance you've selected in the second query? Why not use the same grandfather ID for both queries to be sure? You'll want to check the database to make sure that some child or father isn't being inserted or modified between these two queries, or since the point you gathered that list of father Id values.